# Change color part of text after some time in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have text: `hi ho mi lo tu bo so ad wy`. I want to create functionality that after two seconds next two letters change color from black to red. Example: I show all words: `hi ho mi lo tu bo so ad wy` and `hi` is red. After two seconds `hi` becomes black and `ho` is red. After next two seconds `ho` is black and `mi` is red etc. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is the thing wanted, let me know if you want some changes.(gif animated 7xspeed)

[image]

Full Widget.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FancyText extends StatefulWidget {
  FancyText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FancyTextState createState() => _FancyTextState();
}

class _FancyTextState extends State<FancyText> {
  final _normalStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 24,
  );
  final _redStyle = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
    fontSize: 24,
  );

  int redIndex = 0;

  late Timer timer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        redIndex++;
        if (redIndex > 8) redIndex = 0;
      });
      print("rebuild");
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text.rich(
          TextSpan(children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: "hi ",
              style: redIndex == 0 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "ho ",
              style: redIndex == 1 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "mi  ",
              style: redIndex == 2 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "lo ",
              style: redIndex == 3 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "tu ",
              style: redIndex == 4 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "bo ",
              style: redIndex == 5 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "so ",
              style: redIndex == 6 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "ad ",
              style: redIndex == 7 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "wy ",
              style: redIndex == 8 ? _redStyle : _normalStyle,
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this is almost what I want, but I need to change color only for one element in time. So first only Hi is red, all others are black. After 2 seconds Ho is red and all other items are black etc.

Comment: im glad, if you need more fancy stuff, you can use animated_textKit pub

Comment: I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with Future.delayed.
Write this in future.delayed by editing it. Change a every two seconds. Change colors when a changes.

if(a==1){
.....
a=0;
}else{
...
a=1;
}
When a is 0, a becomes 1 after 2 seconds. This way you get two different states.